# Preserve encryption identity/key moving Windows Media Center to new install of Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, encryption, tv, windows-media-center

My computer is Windows 7 Home Premium x64 with Media Center and a pre-installed TV-Tuner card. I have a collection of movies and tv programs that I have recorded using Media Center.

As I understand it, some movies/programs are marked in some way as "Copy protected" and when those are recorded, they are recorded in such a way (encrypted) that they will only play on my computer.

I want to install a new larger hard drive in the computer, and install a fresh copy of Windows 7 on the computer.

Since I don't know what Media Center uses for its encryption/decryption key, or where this key might be stored, I am concerned that after I do a fresh install of Windows 7, that some of the movies and tv programs that I have already recorded using Media Center will no longer be playable after the new installation of Windows 7.

Will I have to do something (like find and backup/restore this key) after I install Windows 7 on my new hard drive, in order to play these exsisting recordings?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help at all?

"You may be unable to play protected content after your computer hardware changes"

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/891664

Comment: Thanks - those instructions are for Windows Media Player, I'm using Windows Media Center, which is different. It looks like it would solve my problem, but trying to follow the instructions at that link, there are no similar menu choices in Media Center.